# Adding new columns to a dataframe counting the number of entries in certain groups

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Let us say I have a dataframe `df` in PySpark (an interface I'm completely new to) with two columns, one with the label 'sports' that takes only 3 values ('soccer', 'basketball', 'volleyball') and another one with the label 'player_names' which can take any string in its entries.

> How do I create a new dataframe with 3 columns, the first column being just the column 'sports', the second column 'counts' counting the total number of unique player names that play each sport and the third column 'john_counts' being the total number of unique player names that play each sport and that contain the string 'john'?

For instance, if I start with a dataframe with the 2 columns `['soccer', 'volleyball', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'soccer', 'soccer'], ['john doe', 'john wick', 'tom hanks', 'tom haverford', 'john doe', 'michael']` I would like to end up with the dataframe with the 3 columns `['soccer', 'basketball', 'volleyball'], [2,2,1], [1,0,1]`.

In my example, I actually have a very large number of sports in my first column, so solutions that avoid using the small size of 'sports' would be appreciated.

---

Edit Input:

```
+----------+-------------+
|    sports| player_names|
+----------+-------------+
|    soccer|     john doe|
|volleyball|    john wick|
|basketball|    tom hanks|
|basketball|tom haverford|
|    soccer|     john doe|
|    soccer|      michael|
+----------+-------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+----------+------+-----------+
|    sports|counts|john_counts|
+----------+------+-----------+
|    soccer|     2|          1|
|basketball|     2|          0|
|volleyball|     1|          1|
+----------+------+-----------+
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that shows your expected result

Comment: @Psidom thanks for the suggestion, added an example to my question.

Comment: Why is the unique counts `3, 2, 1`, shouldn't it be `2, 2, 1` ? since john doe is duplicate

Comment: @Psidom, absolutely, just corrected it now. Thanks for the help editing the input/output!

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answers if it solved your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop dropduplicates and do a simple group by count(*) and sum with case to attain the results

Code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [
("soccer" ,"john doe"),
("volleyball","john wick"),
("basketball","tom hanks"),
("basketball","tom haverford"),
("soccer", "john doe"),
("soccer",  "michael")
        ]

schema = StructType([
StructField('game', StringType(),True), \
StructField('name', StringType(),True)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema).dropDuplicates()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Data")
spark.sql("select game,count(*),(sum ( case when name like '%john%' then 1 else 0 end ) ) as jo_cnt from Data group by game").show()
```

With Data line by line -

```
>>> data = [
... ("soccer" ,"john doe"),
... ("volleyball","john wick"),
... ("basketball","tom hanks"),
... ("basketball","tom haverford"),
... ("soccer", "john doe"),
... ("soccer",  "michael")
...         ]
>>> schema = StructType([
... StructField('game', StringType(),True), \
... StructField('name', StringType(),True)
... ])

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema).dropDuplicates()
>>> df.show()
+----------+-------------+
|      game|         name|
+----------+-------------+
|volleyball|    john wick|
|basketball|    tom hanks|
|basketball|tom haverford|
|    soccer|     john doe|
|    soccer|      michael|
+----------+-------------+

>>> df.createOrReplaceTempView("Data")
>>> spark.sql("select game,count(*),(sum ( case when name like '%john%' then 1 else 0 end ) ) as jo_cnt from Data group by game").show()
+----------+--------+------+
|      game|count(1)|jo_cnt|
+----------+--------+------+
|basketball|       2|     0|
|    soccer|       2|     1|
|volleyball|       1|     1|
+----------+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupby.agg` with SQL syntax:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.dropDuplicates().groupby('sports').agg(
    f.expr('count(*) as counts'),
    f.expr('sum(case when player_names like "%john%" then 1 else 0 end) as john_counts')
).show()

+----------+------+-----------+
|    sports|counts|john_counts|
+----------+------+-----------+
|basketball|     2|          0|
|    soccer|     2|          1|
|volleyball|     1|          1|
+----------+------+-----------+
```

Where:

1. firstly drop duplicates to guarantee uniqueness;
2. groupby `sports` and count number of unique players;
3. check if player_name contains `john` and sum the trues;

---

Or if you prefer non-SQL syntax:

```
df.dropDuplicates().groupby('sports').agg(
    f.count('*').alias('counts'),
    f.sum(f.col('player_names').contains('john').cast('long')).alias('john_counts')
).show()

+----------+------+-----------+
|    sports|counts|john_counts|
+----------+------+-----------+
|basketball|     2|          0|
|    soccer|     2|          1|
|volleyball|     1|          1|
+----------+------+-----------+
```